# how read/reach/access a file from Kotlin when the application is deployed either in Kubernetes or Linux

Tags: java, linux, kotlin, kubernetes, nio

Context: I successfully parse a json file while debugging/running locally in my Windows PC that way

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Paths

...

val basePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()

val parser: JsonParser = JsonFactory().createParser(File("$basePath/app/src/main/resources/support/certain-file.json"))
```

When I deployed it to either docker or AWS I get this error

```
 /app/src/main/resources/support/certain-file.json (No such file or directory)
```

Is there a more reliable way to "navigate" to a file placed in resources folder? I mean someway it wouldn't be affected either it is Windows/Linux/Kubernetes/etc?

Comment: it depends on where that file is. in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Absolute path should work. Are you sure that file is present in the image running on AWS? No volume that could be mounted on top of a parent folder?

Comment: @Eugene, yes it is under resources folder

Comment: The usual way to access resources is via the classpath, not a filename.  See e.g. [this question](/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin).

Comment: @gidds thanks, now it is working. Kindly, could you give me an overview why  MyCurrentClass::class.java.getResource("/...").readText() works in both Windows as Docker while my above approach based on java.io.File and java.nio.file.Paths only works on Windows? Maybe you can point why you think classpath is the usual/better way and then I will pick your answer up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to access resource files is via the classpath, not by going directly to the filesystem.

There are several advantages to this:

- The resources will usually be deployed automatically, along with your compiled code; no need for manual copying.  (Maven and Gradle usually know to treat the `src/main/resources` folder this way.)
- If you build the application as a .jar/.war file, the resources will get included in that.  (Your code doesn't need to know or care that they're in an archive; as long as you access the resource as a stream, loading just works.)
- The application isn't tied to a particular directory layout or OS; it can run in any directory on any machine.
- You can override files.  Because the classpath can give several locations, a file in a later location can be overridden by adding a file into an earlier location.

It's easy enough to do: just call [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) on the relevant classloader.  In this case, it could be as simple as:

```
val parser = javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("support/certain-file.json")?.use {
    JsonFactory().createParser(it)
}
```

Here `javaClass.classLoader` gets the current class's [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).  (You could use the [system](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader--) one instead, of course.)

[`use()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) takes care of closing the resulting [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) once it's been read.

And luckily, there's a [`createParser()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.html#createParser-java.io.InputStream-) method which accepts the `InputStream`.

(Disclaimer: I don't know anything about Kubernetes, or about running Kotlin/Java programs on Windows.  But the beauty of using the classloader is that you don't need to!  If it can load classes, it can load resources too.)